# Not adding to ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor, console

I have created methods called `generateBookArray()` and `generateBook()`. However, when I call my `addBook()` method it will not add to these. How would I go about this? I am using a switch statement to get user input for a console menu system also. Please find below snipped of each of these methods. The first two methods have been created using arrays.

```
    // Generate books
public static ArrayList<Book> generateBooks(){  
    ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<Book>();

    for(int i = 0; i < title.length; i++){
        bookID[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);

        book.add(new Book(title[i], author[i], category[i], bookID[i], timesLoaned[i], onLoan[i]));     
    }

    return book;
}
```

The generate books array method can be seen below:

```
// Book array
public static Book[] generateBooksArray()
{
    Book[] books = new Book[title.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        books[i] = new Book(title[i], author[i], category[i], bookID[i], timesLoaned[i], onLoan[i]);
    }

    return books;

}
```

Finally, here is my addBook() method:

```
    public static void add(Scanner sc){
    // Takes information from user
    System.out.print("Enter a title:");
    String title = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter an title:");
    String author = sc.nextLine();

    // Randomly generates book number
    int bookID = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000));

    ArrayList<Book> newBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
    Book book = new Book(title, author, null, bookID, 0, false);
    newBook = HelperUtilities.generateBooks();
    newBook.add(book);

    System.out.println("Book has been added.");
}
```

Another method which may be helpful in assisting me would be the createLibrary method:

```
// Creating library
public static ArrayList<Library> createLibrary(){
    // Variables holding the information
    int[] ID = {1};
    String[] name = {"Draperstown"};
    String[] address = {"Magherafelt Road, Draperstown"};
    String[] phone = {"028 796 27436"};

    // temp variables
    int newID = -1;
    String newName = null;
    String newAdd = null;
    String newPhone = null;

    ArrayList<Library> library = new ArrayList<Library>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        // setting temp values to equal existing variables
        newID = ID[i];
        newName = name[i];
        newAdd = address[i];
        newPhone = phone[i];

        // Adding a new library with the books
        library.add(new Library(newID, newName, newAdd, newPhone, generateBooks()));
    } 
    // returns the library array list
    return library;
}
```

Thank you all in advance. All questions and recommendations are welcome :) This is my first few months coding in Java so its all new to me in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

There where you say "Finally, here is my addBook() method" there is no `addBook()` method.  But there is an `add()` method, which creates a local `ArrayList<Book>`, adds a book to it, prints "book has been added", and then returns, without returning anything, thus allowing the new `ArrayList` to be immediately garbage-collected, and along with it the book that was added to it.

You need to pass a `Collection<Book>` to your `add()` method, for it to add a book to it.  If `Collection<Book>` confuses you, then never mind, just pass an `ArrayList<Book>` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. When you say return something in the add() method do you mean a return as in return the new book or the array list?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you call generate books and then add a book to the resulting list and then you aren't seeing it when you call generatebooks again.

Your add call should be working properly.  The issue is that you throw away the array you created and added the new book to.

It's unclear where 'title' is declared but that seems to be your only longterm storage of all the books.  I'm not sure where the create library stuff come in.

Comment: Thanks, what method should be edited to fix this throw away array. I am still a student at Uni and this has gotten the better off me, slowing down my assignment.

Comment: You need to assign your arraylist to a class or object level variable.  i.e. something declared outside of a method.

Comment: Like in the main method?

Comment: No, outside of a method.  The main method is a method.